# Unable to get two containers (in two different networks) to talk to each other

Tags: docker

As you can see in the image below, there are two containers and each which contains one container. I am trying to get these two containers to talk to each other but failed to accomplish it so far.

[image]

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

This is what I did so far.

**1. Create two networks.**

```
$ docker network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --driver bridge net_1
$ docker network create --subnet 192.168.2.0/24 --driver bridge net_2
```

List

```
NETWORK ID          NAME            DRIVER              SCOPE
8a9ae0d69c9c        net_1           bridge              local
e8a8460784d0        net_2           bridge              local
```

Inspections details

- [net_1](https://pastebin.com/UPFY6D95)
- [net_2](https://pastebin.com/a2q4qu6K)

**2. Create containers.**

```
$ docker run -i -t -d -p 5011:80 --network=net_1 --ip 192.168.1.11 --name=app_1_con app_1_img
$ docker run -i -t -d -p 5022:80 --network=net_2 --ip 192.168.2.22 --name=app_2_con app_2_img
```

List

```
ID  IMAGE      COMMAND      STATUS  PORTS                  NAMES
f6  app_1_img  "/bin/bash"  Up      0.0.0.0:5011->80/tcp   app_1_con
0a  app_2_img  "/bin/bash"  Up      0.0.0.0:5022->80/tcp   app_2_con
```

Inspection details

- [app_1_con](https://pastebin.com/h46bN07p)
- [app_2_con](https://pastebin.com/XMqLiJk3)

**Test**

Both of these commands hangs and dies at the end.

```
$ docker exec -it app_1_con ping 192.168.2.22
PING 192.168.2.22 (192.168.2.22) 56(84) bytes of data.

$ docker exec -it app_2_con ping 192.168.1.11
PING 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Comment: I left an answer for possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613904/1251684).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a docker-compose.yml file with the following:

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  app_1:
    image: alpine:3.7
    container_name: app_1_con
    ports:
      - "5011:80"
    networks:
      net_1:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.1.11"
      net_2:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.2.11"
    command: ping 192.168.2.22

  app_2:
    image: alpine:3.7
    container_name: app_2_con
    ports:
      - "5022:80"
    networks:
      net_2:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.2.22"
    command: tail -f /dev/null # this keeps the container running

networks:

  net_1:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24

  net_2:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
```

then run the example using: `docker-compose up`
and use `Ctrl-C` to stop the containers.

Details:

First start using docker compose when things are anything but trivial. It makes maintenance and understanding a lot easier.

As you should be able to see, you need to have one container be part of the same network as the other. This is a very common pattern to add network security. For instance:

```
  -----> nginx  --------> app server  -------> db
       pub + priv           priv                priv
       networks             network             network
```

Only your web proxy needs to be in the public network (the one exposed by the `ports` attribute). Your app server and db can be in a private network not accessible from the outside. Nginx is the only container that would need to be part of two networks.

Something else, the Docker daemon has its own DNS resolver so you don't need to refer to containers by their IP. Simply use their `service` name instead. For instance instead of

```
command: ping 192.168.2.22
```

simply use

```
command: ping app_2
```

Comment: So one way or another forcing a container in a network to communicate with a container in another network exposes security risk. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Sure but then you need your containers to talk to each other right? You can't put security absolutely everywhere. It becomes a nightmare to manage and it reduces performance. You specify a "trusted network" like `priv` above where containers can connect to each other using http (not https), no auth (except for db) and no firewall. You do however put a strong wall at the proxy level (nginx).

Comment: Is this a typo `ipv4_address: "192.168.2.11"` in your `app_1` config? Is it not supposed to be `ipv4_address: "192.168.2.22"` instead? I haven't started using docker-compose.yml so I'll try it later in the future. However, I'll accept your answer as it seems better option. I made it work by adding `app_2_con` to `net_1` as you suggested.

Comment: @BentCoder It's not a mistake. `192.168.2.11` is the IP address that app_1 has on the second network `net_2`. You also don't need to add `net_1` to `app_2_con` since it doesn't need to connect to `app_2_con`. The other container does that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is **no routing** between net_1 and net_2,

One option is to put them in the same network like this:

```
$ docker run -i -t -d -p 5011:80 --network=net_1 --ip 192.168.1.11 --name=app_1_con app_1_img
$ docker run -i -t -d -p 5022:80 --network=net_1 --ip 192.168.1.10 --name=app_2_con app_2_img
```

I usually put **containers which should communicate between each other** in the **same network**,

**Example:**

1) First Application (App1):

**component1_app1** in **backend_app1_net**

**component2_app1** in **backend_app1_net**

2) Second Application (App2):

**component1_app2** in **backend_app2_net**

**component2_app2** in **backend_app2_net**

3) Notes:

If I wanted the **component1_app1** to communicate with the all components of **app2**, I will also wire him to **backend_app2_net**,

If I wanted the **component1_app1** to communicate with only **component2_app2** I would create a new network and I will wire **component1_app1** and  **component2_app2** to it.

Comment: What about showing us the solution to my question rather than telling us how you do things?

Comment: Sadly this is more of a proposition rather than an answer. I know hot to create a single network and stick containers in it to make the system work. However, my question is different. Thanks for taking time to providing a proposition anyway.

Comment: This may help you https://serverfault.com/questions/830135/routing-among-different-docker-networks-on-the-same-host-machine

Comment: I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613904/1251684) the issue with the same way but I'll test @Alkaline 's answer first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default bridge network when running two containers. Or create one network with docker network create. Then the two containers use the network.